# LaTex hierarchy levels

Tags: vocabulary

there is this tool LaTex for writing paper. It has a couple of hierarchy levels namely:

> part
>
> chapter
>
> section
>
> subsection
>
> subsubsection
>
> paragraph
>
> subparagraph

what would be good (meaningful) translation for these? I know `Kapitel` and `Abschnitt` are very common as well with the prefix `Unter-`. But what would be a good differentiation (in words not in explanations) for the above mentioned levels?

E.g. in referencing: See subsection 5

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: chapter is translated to Kapitel and Abschnitt depending on the dictionary. Same for section. It could be Kapitel or Abschnitt. Depending on the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use the following translations:

- part -> Teil
- chapter -> Kapitel
- section -> Abschnitt
- subsection -> Unterabschnitt
- subsubsection -> Unterabschnitt (perhaps Unterunterabschnitt, if you really need to differentiate between these, but that sounds really weird and noone would use it)
- paragraph -> Absatz
- subparagraph -> Unterabsatz

You then use: "siehe Unterabschnitt 5" as a translation for "see subsection 5"

Comment: These are exactly the words that are in [this](https://www.namsu.de/Extra/strukturen/Inhaltsverzeichnis.html) german documentation... subsubsection there is translated as Unter-Unterabschnitt

Comment: *Lyx* (a TeX-Editor) uses "Unterunterabschnitt", "Paragraph" and "Unterparagraph" in its German GUI

Comment: "but that sounds really weird and noone would use it" - consider the context: Is it really weirder than *subsubsection* is in English?

Comment: @O. R. Mapper I stand corrected - I wouldn't have thought that Unterunterabschnitt might be used. But then, a technical documentation is a kind of its own.

Comment: A *Paragraph* in German is a section of a law. When dealing with texts in general this term should be avoided in German because it can be confused with an English paragraph which is an *Absatz* in German, as shown in the answer.